# ¿Sentado o parado? / OmegaUp / Algoritmos

Tags: c++

¡Saludos comunidad!

Estoy resolviendo en la plataforma OmegaUp el siguiente problema:

**Problema**

El músico te ha pedido tu ayuda para que respondas la siguiente pregunta: Si todos los que compraron boleto vienen al concierto, ¿cuántas personas estarán sentadas y cuántas estarán paradas?

**Entrada**

La primer línea de la entrada consistirá en dos enteros, r y s, el número de filas y el número de asientos por fila.

La segunda línea contendrá un sólo entero, b, que representa entre el número de boletos que se han vendido.

**Salida**

La salida deberá consistir en dos enteros separados por un espacio: el número de personas que estarán sentadas y las que permanecerán paradas, respectivamente.

Recuerda que todos intentarán sentarse si pueden.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

He resuelto el problema y este es mi codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int r,s,b,sentado,parado;
    scanf("%d %d\n",&r,&s);
    scanf("%d",&b);

    sentado=r*s;
    parado=b-sentado;

    printf("%d %d",sentado,parado);
    return 0;
}
```

El problema es que el estado de mi codigo es "PARCIALMENTE CORRECTA", lo que significa que funciona para algunos casos, pero para otros no.

Quisiera saber ¿qué no he tomado en cuenta?

Comment: Solo hay 3 casos posibles: se venden **menos** boletos que sitio. Se venden **los mismos** boletos que sitios. Se venden **mas** boletos que sitios. ¿ Los has probado todos ?

Comment: Lo acabo de probar. Tienes razón, no considere esto.
Si me funciono!
Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Aunque pensando bien podrías añadir un `if` al final

```
if (parado <= 0 )
  {
     printf(" Aun hay ", abs(parado), "acientos libres o vacios ");
  }
```

Eso te ayudará también a que la respuesta no sea negativa sino positiva